# Is there any browser based XHTML editor which we can use to make text to xhtml conversion?

Tags: css, xhtml

Is there any browser based XHTML editor which we can use to make text to xhtml conversion?

If PC dosen't have any IDE or tool other than Notepad and we can't install anything on PC due to restrictions.

Then what is fast and good way to make .txt or word 2007 document to clean valid xhtml code?

Comment: Define "Text to XHTML" conversion. What does the text look like that you want to convert?

Comment: @Pekka - simple paragraphs, with headings, bold text, and tables

Comment: Browser based? Don't you mean web based?

Comment: @Balus - yes browser based, web based- same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure if this is what you are looking for .. but you can take a look at

1. [tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
2. [CKEdtior](http://ckeditor.com/)